# cannot ApplyEdits in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, editing

I have a map service that suddenly stopped taking edits. It is an AGS map service with data stored in SQL 2012 r2. I can consume the servcie in a web map and try to edit it. I get NO errors or warning when I move a point or edit an attribute, but when I save the map and reload the page, the edits didn't take. In the Network console of the Chrome developer tools, the applyEdits function shows empty brackets, whereas it usually includes updated attribute or geometry information. Any ideas on why ApplyEdits suddenly stopped working?

I have tried to republish the map service and restart it but still no luck.

Comment: Do you have debug logs on your server so you can see if anything is happening there to your feature service.

Comment: @RussRoberts I checked the logs and nothing is failing and nothing looks out of the ordinary. I honestly think there is something wrong in AGOL and it's not capturing the updated info for the applyEdits function.

Comment: Also it only happens with specific layers in the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my schema was corrupted. I was able to figure this out by trying to export the schema, and import it back into a new feature dataset. I experienced the same issues. When I recreated the schema manually (Real pain in the a**) it worked fine. I also had to create new global IDs. The old ones appeared to be a part of the problem too.

So in short, I recreated the schema manually and added new globalIDs. Also, don't EVER force delete schema locks (someone else had been doing this and it caused the corruption).